# To rerboot Wi-Fi adapter using command line

Tags: android

I am trying to restart Wi-Fi of my Android after a certain activity. I have tried it using ADB command given below, which is not working. Can anyone tell me what is the problem? Is there any other way to do that? FYI, My phone is ROOTed & I'm using Android version 4.1.2.

```
    try {

    String[] cmd3 = { "svc wifi disable" };
    String[] cmd4 = { "svc wifi enable" };

    Process off = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd3);
    off.waitFor();

    Process on = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd4);
    on.waitFor();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The `svc` command requires you to run it as `su`- which you haven't done as shown in your codes. Search Stackoverflow for posts that show you how to run command requiring elevated privilege like `svc` via `su`.

Comment: This is still not working and simply hanged with crash the apps. I have used `String[] cmd3 = { "su", "svc wifi disable" };` & `String[] cmd4 = { "su", "svc wifi enable" };`

Comment: To run it successfully, you will need something lile: `su -c svc wifi enable`. Note: You need to specify the `-c` option to run `su`. Also, run the command via an `AsyncTask` so you don't hang the main UI thread. You can find `AsyncTask` documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).